# lua: how can i get the raw string in __tostring metamethod?

Tags: lua

code below:

```
local t = {}
setmetatable(t, {__tostring = function(self) return 'MyTable is: '..tostring(self) end})
print(t)
```

running the code will cause error: "C stack overflow". Because in __tostring metamethod, tostring(self) will invoke the __tostring metamethod, that's a dead loop.

Is there a way to get the raw string of the value "t"?

Comment: If you remove the tostring( ) call, it would work. It would show something like `MyTable is: table:0x2132542`.

Comment: @Moop: I think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: if i remove the tostring(), it cause the error:attempt to concatenate a table value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you're trying to do from Lua, you basically have to unset the metatable from the main table, then call `tostring` on it, then set the metatable back. Like this:

```
setmetatable(t, {__tostring = function(self)
  local temp = getmetatable(self)
  setmetatable(self, nil)
  local ret = 'MyTable is: ' .. tostring(self)
  setmetatable(self, temp)
  return ret
end,
})
```

Also, note that the `__tostring` metafunction is supposed to *return* the string, not merely print it.

Comment: That is a solution. Thank you. But i cannot change the metatable if there is a protection of the table.

Comment: @isaf: What do you mean by "a protection of the table"? So long as the `setmetatable` function exists and is unmodified, there is no way to stop someone from being able to set the metatable.

Comment: if the metatable has the field "__metatable",  it cannot be changed by the setmetatable.But i found it can be changed by debug.setmetatable.

Comment: @Llamageddon: What do you mean by that? You cannot access the same Lua state from different threads at all, and two separate Lua states contain entirely disconnected data from one another. So this is no more "thread-safe" than any other construct in Lua.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ahhh, you are correct indeed, thanks :-P